# how to properly reference `dir` in the step attribute of a popper workflow?

Tags: docker, containers, popper

I'm having trouble when I try to use the `dir` attribute of a step in my workflow. I have a directory like the following:

```
myproject/
  folder/
    subfolder/
```

And this is how my workflow looks like:

```
steps:
- uses: docker://alpine:3.12
  dir: folder/subfolder
  args: [pwd]
```

The above is stored in a `wf.yml` file, and I run it by doing:

```
cd myproject/

popper run -f wf.yml
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR: Schema validation failed:
 - Key 'dir' was not defined. Path: '/steps/1'.
```

I am using Popper 2.6.0, and Docker 19.03.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dir` feature in Popper is available in version 2.7.0+, so you will need to update to a newer version. In addition, as specified in [the documentation](https://popper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sections/cn_workflows.html#changing-the-working-directory), the path given to the `dir` attribute of a step has to be an absolute path. In the given example, since the folder being referenced is within the `myproject/` folder, which is the one getting bind-mounted to `/workspace` inside the container, the workflow would look like:

```
steps:
- uses: docker://alpine:3.12
  dir: /workspace/folder/subfolder
  args: [pwd]
```

and the above should print `/workspace/folder/subfolder`.